# Align text in an ordered list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, tei

I'm constructing HTML from XML ([TEI](https://tei-c.org/)) source and need to implement line numbering.
the allignment of the text is not satisfactory as you may see:

[image]

Currently, it looks in HTML like this

```html
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l8">
9   liecht •Und got ſach das liecht ,
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l9">
10  das es gut was vnd ſchid das 
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l10">
```

The approaches with table or list would not be a good option because of how HTML is created with XSLT and how source data looks like. So maybe
there are any other alternatives like using `<span>` and CSS?

Comment: Sorry, aligned where?... Why don't you use OL and LIs?

Comment: Vertically. As you may see the 'd' in the second line starts a little bit later then the 'l' in the first line.

Comment: Well, use the appropriate markup tags as I said. OL (ordered list) will do the trick.

Comment: I have some complicated file structure. Also the numbering is calculated elsewhere, I don't need it to be automatically. I there a way using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have control over the generated html. So you could enclose the numbers in a `<span>` tag and style it with css. Something like:

```css
.lineNumber {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l8">
<span class="lineNumber">9</span>liecht •Und got ſach das liecht ,
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l9">
<span class="lineNumber">10</span>das es gut was vnd ſchid das
<br label="#region_1641631166648_18l10">
```

With this you could also align the numbers correctly underneath.